# No internet when wireguard is connected

Tags: fedora, wireguard

I’ve been using F37 for a while since it was released and Wireguard was working fine.
This happens right after the latest update yesterday.

My laptop Wireguard config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = redacted
Address = 10.1.0.12/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

[Peer]
PublicKey = redacted
PresharedKey = redacted
Endpoint = redacted
AllowedIPs = 10.1.0.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

If I change the AllowedIPs to `0.0.0.0/0` - it works.
But i do not want to route everything to Wireguard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the specific DNS entry:

```
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
```

More information of this issue is available here:
https://blogs.gnome.org/mcatanzaro/2020/12/17/understanding-systemd-resolved-split-dns-and-vpn-configuration/